# Access Issue, AutoExec, Runcode Error, 2001

Tags: ms-access

I've inherited a split Access database with four pieces, backend version, frontend version and two user versions in accde form.

The users wanted some changes, so I needed to add a few forms, modify a few forms, add a table and come up with the queries for the changes.  That work is complete and working well, but I wasn't able to convert the new frontend accdb version to the user accde versions.

I'm getting an AutoExec, Runcode Error 2045.  As a temporary solution for the users I posted the accdb versions, but most are getting a AutoExec, Runcode Error 2001.  Some of the users are able to open the database, but all the team members need to be able to get in.  I'm wondering what the differences  would be between the users who are able to get in and those that aren't.

I've added the location to the trusted sites and I've changed their macro settings with no success.

Comment: *"I'm getting an AutoExec, Runcode Error 2045"* - you'll have to be more specific than that. This is probably an error message created from your code, you need to find out where exactly, and post that code.

Comment: Hi Andre,  Thanks for responding.  Since the post, I tried to Debug and Compile and a Compact and Repair and I'm getting an Error Code of 2425 when I try to open the accde version.  I inherited this database and it was working previously before I made the changes I did, but I didn't touch the code.  Here it is if you think it'll help...  thanks

Comment: Public Function GetUserInfo() myLogin = ap_GetUserName() myPos = GetPosition() myName = GetName() If myPos = 10 Then myID = DLookup("UserID", "SAUsers", "Login = '" & myLogin & "'") myDept = 0 Else myID = DLookup("UserID", "tblEmployees", "Login = '" & myLogin & "'")     myDept = DLookup("Department", "tblEmployees", "Login = '" & myLogin & "'") End If End Function